# How to change mouse scrollwheel lines on an Acer Aspire 7741?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, touchpad, acer-aspire, mouse-wheel

My Acer Aspire mousewheel is set to the default setting and I need to increase the amount of lines it scrolls by. Normally this wouldn't be a problem on Windows 7, but the Mouse Properties Window does not have a section for "Wheel" since there is a touchpad. I am using just a basic mouse, so I don't think it has any special software to allow me to change the mousewheel lines through that.

When I go to "Change Mouse Wheel Settings" in Control Panel, I get the window of Mouse Properties to change the pointing device orientation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to find the **wheel** tab no button tab

Edit : Its a long standing issue on these alps pointing devices

My suggestion : first create a system restore point before proceeding

Try updating alps device driver after checking version number

X64

http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/TouchPad/TouchPad_ALPS_7.105.2015.1107_W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634061191971714555&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%207741&OS=711&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6

X86

http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/TouchPad/TouchPad_ALPS_7.5.2015.1107_W7x86_A.zip?acerid=634061191073662493&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%207741&OS=712&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=PA_6

If that does not help

Disable the alps pointing device in device manager

else Disable the pointing device in bios

else completely uninstall alps pointing device from device manager by selecting delete , at which point you will use the default windows pointing device which will allow to edit wheel setting, albeit you will lose gesture touchpad support if it support that

[image]

Comment: You are correct, but I do not have that tab on my computer. I accidentally posted Buttons instead of Wheel. Edited my post.

Comment: So Let me guess you have a basic mouse and a integrated touch-pad ! does the touch-pad have It's driver installed ! and if you please upload the screenshot of the mouse property window you getting

Comment: I just added a picture of what I get when I search for "Change Mouse Wheel Settings"

Comment: Did you find a solution !

Comment: No I didnt find one